# Free Windows 10 software for trimming videos (e.g. .mp4) from 2-10 GB?

Tags: video-editing

Can you please recommend free software for my Windows 10 laptop, to trim videos from 2 to 10 GB?

I've tried [Lightworks, ShotCut](https://www.techradar.com/best/free-video-editing-software). But they keep freezing after I apply my trim, and I must force-close and force-quit the program with Windows Task Manager.

Is my laptop too powerless or strengthless? Here are its specifications germane to my question.

1. 6th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ Processor (2.60GHz 6MB)
2. NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 960M 4GB
3. 16GB DDR4 2133 MHz
4. 1TB 5400 RPM + 512GB PCIe SSD
5. 17.3" FHD (1920 X 1080) IPS Anti-Glare with integrated camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably overkill, but [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) - Mac, Win & Nix - is freeware unless you're a pro video editor who needs hardware integretion.

That's literally one of the world's best video edit suites… for free. I honestly have no idea why it's not mentioned in that review, it's right up there with Final Cut Pro & Adobe Premier.

Otherwise, people tend to use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) for simple, task-driven edits, but it's command-line.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to cut video, you can look like at https://github.com/0x90d/YALC it's an easy to use software to cut video without loosing quality with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/index.html).

> Avidemux is a free video editor designed for **simple cutting**, filtering and encoding tasks. It supports many file types, including AVI, DVD compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF, using a variety of codecs.

Quote from their site, emphasis mine.